# How can I make DataTable enumerable?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, .net-2.0, enumerable

I cannot use AsEnumerable() on DataTable, I'm using C# 3 but I'm just targeting 2.0 framework (LINQ capability is courtesy of [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/)).  Is there any way I can make DataTable enumerable without using Select() ?

```
bool isExisting = (bdsAttachments.DataSource as DataTable).Select().Any(xxx => (string)dr["filename"] == filename);
```

Update:

I wanted it to make it look like this:

```
bool isExisting = (bdsAttachments.DataSource as DataTable).AsEnumerable().Any(xxx => (string)dr["filename"] == filename);
```

I'm getting an inkling that the Select method of DataTable returns a copy, I'm thinking to just use AsEnumerable, the problem is I'm just targeting 2.0 framework, System.Data.DataSetExtensions is not available

BTW, i tried this: http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2006/01/15/284.aspx, but has compilation errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> EnumerateRows(this DataTable table)
    {
        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            yield return row;
        }
    }
```

Allows you to call:

```
bool isExisting = (bdsAttachments.DataSource as DataTable).EnumerateRows().Any(dr => (string)dr["filename"] == filename);
```

Comment: your answer compels me to dig dipper on IEnumerable ^_^ i googled it, i found this http://www.developerfusion.com/article/9397/iterator-blocks-in-c-2-autogenerated-state-machines/ really enlightening

Answer (score 5):

1. `IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable();` (System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll)
2. `IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>();` (System.Core.dll)

Answer (score 2):

Keeping your enumerator strictly 2.0:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRow> getRows(DataTable table)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        yield return row;
    }
}
```

Then call with linqbridge like this:

```
bool isExisting = getRows(bdsAttachments.DataSource as DataTable).Any(row => (string)row["filename"] == filename);
```

Comment: Select is not available on .Rows, be it from 2.0 framework or 3.5 framework

Answer (score 1):

You can try casting the DataTable as IEnumerable and iterate over the set:

```
//your data exists as a DataTable
DataTable dt = (DataTable)bdsAttachments.DataSource;
foreach (DataRow row in dt)
{
    if (row["filename"] == filename)
        return row;
}
```

The foreach will iterate through the list and search of the filename (I assume you're searching for the first DataRow with that filename, not all rows that match the filename).

Comment: IListSource.GetList() don't map to LINQ's Any extension method. LINQ's methods are available only on enumerables

Comment: I thought the idea was the NOT use LINQ (hence the .NET Framework 2.0 requirement).