# C# Framework 2 DataTable to IENumerable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, frameworks

I need to convert a DataTable to IEnumerable then use LinqBridge properly... I need to parse a `SELECT * FROM X` query into a `Query.GroupBy(l => l.Field);` in order to use some `foreach` loops correctly grouping my query...

I've tried

```
public static IEnumerable<DataRow> getRows(DataTable table)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        yield return row;
    }
}
```

But I can't use `getRows(myDataTable).Any()` or other Linq functions... Some help please.

I can't upgrade from Framework 2, my department wants to downgrade from my 4.0 app to 2.0 because they absoluty deny upgrading the computers, so now I'm very frustrated because my app was WPF 4.0 and I'm migrating everything to WinForm (which is a mess) and updating every method...

Thank you so much.

**EDIT**

Found the problem, I was calling `using LinqBridge` but forgot to add after that `using System.Linq` now the problem is solved and everything working... Delete this post please, or leave it here in order to guide people like me and let them know they need to call System.Linq...

Comment: I didn't think Linq was supported on .NET 2.0? From memory, it first arrived in 3.5...

Comment: Are you using the 3.5 framework (which is part of the 2.0 runtime)?  If you are, you can use the `AsEnumerable()` extension on the DataTable, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5298438/745969).

Comment: I am using 2.0 Framework, can't use AsEnumerable(), so this was the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I was calling using LinqBridge but forgot to add after that `using System.Linq` now the problem is solved and everything working with the method I've posted on my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the DataTable.Select method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.80).aspx